# How to write a test class for HTTPCallout in batch class

Tags: unit-test, batch, httpcalloutmock

I have a batch class which contains HTTP callout, I have seen the blogs for it [httpcalloutmock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm), But I am not understanding how to do it in batch class.
Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [execute the batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_2.htm):

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new YourMock());

// Any data setup goes here

Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(new YourBatchable());
Test.stopTest();
```

and the [HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) will get called from your asynchronously executed batchable because the [Test.stopTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_stopTest) that ensures:

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected
>   by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes
>   are run synchronously.

Comment: @isTest 
public with sharing class MetadataBatchTest{
               
  static testmethod void metadataBatchTestMethod(){
  
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
    Test.startTest();
         MetadataBatch batchObj = new MetadataBatch('SELECT Id FROM Custom_String__c');
         Id processId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj,200);
     Test.stopTest(); 
   }
}

Comment: This my test class and it still gives me the same error " Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts"

Comment: @MarufBagwan I don't know the cause of the problem. I suggest you ask a new question including the source code of both the test and the batchable and any line number information that is part of the error.